# How do I stop an update panel from refreshing on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I an update panel with a couple dependent dropdown lists. When the Submit button is clicked the panel refreshes and the dropdowns reset. The user parameters are lost. Is there a way to add code that will stop the update panel from refreshing that I could include in my button click event?

Update Panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True"     UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <li class="small_link"> ..........
 <li class="small_link">
                                    <div class="li_div">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnInventoryRpt" runat="server" Text="Load Report" OnClick="btnInventoryRpt_Click"
                                        CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="False"  />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ContentTemplate>            
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Button Click Event:

```
protected void btnInventoryRpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            load_inventory_report();

    }
```

Comment: You should put the `Button` out side of the `UpdatePanel`

Comment: [Microsoft - Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) here a a few examples with Asynchronus postback with dropdown list

Comment: Avijit - it still refreshes the update panel when I place the button out side the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me that you are binding your dropdownlists in the page load event but you are forgetting the page postback.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {                
            //Bind your drowdown list here
        }
    }
```

But could use a little more code from you to be sure.

Comment: I have tried this and it prevents my selected index changed events not to fire int he update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I was able to accomplish this using the AsyncPostBackTrigger. This is a good explanation if anyone else runs into this issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your asp.net page remove the ChildreAsTrigger attribute from your updatepanel tag.  You only need to UpdateMode="Conditional" to force an update

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" />
```

In your button click event you can then force the update

```
protected void btnInventoryRpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    load_inventory_report();
    UpdatePanel2.Update();
}
```